# PHP if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/')

Tags: php

I am trying to display a banner on the front page of my shopping cart, but not the rest of the pages on my site. I am using the code below, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```
<?php 
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/") 
    { 
        print '<img src=\"images/banner_2.jpg\">; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Try and `var_dump()` `$_SERVER`

Comment: What about `if(!strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))`? This could be a typo, but you're not closing the string.

Comment: FYI: You don't need to escape doublequotes within a single-quoted string

Comment: There's a chance that REQUEST_URI could be "" instead of "/" -- depending on the server implementation. It's not supposed to be, but there you go.

Comment: @Galen, you changed the code and not my #2 point is moot!

Comment: @Galen: Why did you correct the syntax error in the question?

Comment: I assumed it was an error when typing it into SO, reverted.

Answer (score 3):

This should work everywhere:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') === '') {
  print '<img src="images/banner_2.jpg">';
}
```

Only issue is that if for whatever reason the HTTP server does not provide `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, you will end up with a banner on every page.

Comment: I used your method, but still no image appearing.  I've double checked the image destination.

Comment: @Tim what do you get if you `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`?