# Why can't my custom 404 handler see my static content?

Tags: php, apache, seo, http-status-code-404, handler

I decided to use SEO friendly urls in my project. That's why I send all requests through my 404 custom handler (index.php)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

this is the place where I check for the path in the URI

```
if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
 $path_begin_expected = "/page/";
 $path_begin_evaluated= substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strlen($path_begin_expected));
 if($path_begin_expected == $path_begin_evaluated ){
    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($path_begin_expected), strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
 }
 else {
    $page = null;
 }
}
else {
 $page = null;
}
```

Then I use $page to decide what to return to user

```
switch($page)
{
case 'main':
    include("webapps/main/pages/main_bc.php");
    break;
...other cases here
}
```

I also used

```
Alias /page c:/work/Languator/trunk/php/htdocs/my_application/
```

Now, if

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

is correct (ie. the request has the path that exists on the server) requests like these work OK

```
/page/home or /page/help-1 or /page/more-docs
```

But when I use these requests:

```
/page2/home or /pag/help-1 or /pagex/more-docs/
```

No css files or js files or img pictures are loaded. My browser asks for these files like this:

```
mydomain/page2/css/styles.css
mydomain/pag/css/styles.css
mydomain/pagex/more-docs/css/styles.css !!!
```

but obviously these paths don't exist.

Can somebody explain why is that? 
How can I replace

```
path2 into path
pag into path
pagex/more-docs into path
```

or there is another solution to this problem?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653869/php-if-serverrequest-uri

Comment: @shnisaka I can't see any relation of the above link with my question. Can you explain your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you link to your CSS and JS files from your error document, you should not use relative links.   Start your CSS and JS links with either `/` or `http://example.com/`.  Both of the following would be acceptable.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

Another solution would be to include a `base` tag in the head of your page that tells the browser how to interpret all relative links:

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```